# Pass more parameter in overriding new operator(C++)

Tags: c++, overriding, operator-keyword

I want to override new operator in C++, by following the instructions at http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/operator_new.html

```
    class CMyclass
    {
    public:
           CMyClass(BOOL bUseWhichMemManager);
            void* operator new(size_t);
            void operator delete(void*);
    };
```

I create two memory manager called CMemManager1 and CMemMangaer2, using different algorithms to allocate buffer. Now I want to control which memory manager to be used, when calling new.

I try to add a parameter bUseWhichMemManager to the constructor, but in overrided new function, there are no way to access the parameter. Is there a way to pass more parameters to new operator, such as:

```
    void* operator new(size_t size, BOOL bUseWhichManager);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters to an allocation function (*i.e.* `operator new`) in the *new-expression* like this:

```
new (b) CMyClass // passes "b" to "bUseWhichManager"
```

assuming you had the following declaration of `operator new` as a member of `CMyClass`, as in your question:

```
void* operator new(size_t size, BOOL bUseWhichManager);
```

(Don't put the parameter in the constructor, as it doesn't make sense, probably.)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a [placement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) syntax to be defined for you custom allocation. Like:

```
void *
operator new (std::size_t size, CMemManager1& manager)
{
    return manger.allocate(size) ;
}

void
operator delete (void * p, CMemManager1& manager)
{
   manager.deallocate(p) ;
}

void *
operator new (std::size_t size, CMemManager2& manager)
{
    return manger.allocate(size) ;
}

void
operator delete (void * p, CMemManager2& manager)
{
   manager.deallocate(p) ;
}
```

and then

```
CMemManager1 manager1;
CMemManager2 manager2;

CMyclass * p1 = new (manager1) CMyclass ;
CMyclass * p2 = new (manager2) CMyclass ;

// It is a placement syntax so you should call your destructor manually.
p1->~CMyclass();
p2->~CMyclass();

operator delete(p1, manager1);
operator delete(p2, manager2);
```

Comment: Do we need the `CMemManager1::operator delete(p1,manager1)` if the `operator delete` is defined as member function?

Answer (score 0):

Using the placement operator

```
#include<new>
#include<memory>
class A {
    // Some stuff
};

A* a = (A*) _mm_malloc(sizeof(A),16);
// Now call the ctor without allocation
new a A(/* some arguments */);

// Delete
_mm_free(a);
```